# php cache expiration time for file_exists() or similiar functions

Tags: php

as per php documentation for [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php)

> The results of this function are cached. See clearstatcache() for
>   more details.

But it doesn't provide information for how long php will hold this information in cache. I've checked documentation for [clearstatcache()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php)
but no such information is there. Googling also not helped this time.

I'm building an application where file_exists is called to generate some output, and since the file being checked can be removed by any time by any user, i need to be sure if it really exists before generating output.

Calling clearcache() before file_exists() will solve the purpose, but just for curiosity I'd like to know for how long PHP will cache files information (default time) and by which variable i can this change cache expiration time?

**EDIT 1:** In real, checking again with file_exists() after deleting file returns false, but if it is so, what is the meaning of cache as written in documentation ?

**EDIT 2:**

```
<? 
var_dump(file_exists('/home/user/filecheck.php')); 
sleep(20);
// after running script, sleep for 20 seconds just to quickly delete this file manually before file_exists is called again.
// unlink is not used since as per documentation it'll clear php cache.
var_dump(file_exists('/home/user/filecheck.php')); 
?>
```

and the response of script is

```
boolean true

boolean false
```

That means php is not caching file_exists information if file exists even for same execution, then why it is written in documentation that "the results of this function are cached"?

Comment: PHP caches that information for the duration of the request

Comment: duration of request ???

Comment: PHP executes individual requests to the webserver, each in its own thread; and when the response is returned to the webbrowser, then the request terminates

Comment: so you mean it caches for current execution of script.

Comment: Yes, the cache is wiped when PHP ceases executing each individual request

Comment: @MarkBaker, please reread the edited question.

Comment: See  comment in [this bug report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28790) - `You guys realize that the stat cache is per-request, right? You only need to clear the stat cache before a file_exists() call if you A. did a stat for it, and B. either created or deleted it on that request. In which case you shouldn't need 
to stat it again since the success status of the create/delete will tell you 
whether the file is there or not. Perhaps for long-running daemons or something this becomes more of an issue, but for a typical web request the stat cache typically saves you dozens of system calls.`

Comment: The above is where I understood that the cache is for the duration of the request, which is from the PHP internals team..... I have no explanation of why it isn't working in this way for you

Comment: @MarkBaker Youre pointing to bug with date: 2004-06-15 15:43  isn't it strange to think of it now. I think this issue is fixed during 11 years...

Comment: but I don't care, I'm trying to be away from php, cuz this lang/interpretator become mainstream, everybody are "pro" with php (:  I prefer nodejs for now, but maybe in future switch to D language.

Comment: @num8er - I was specifically pointing to a comment in the bug that specifically answered the OPs question about the duration of the cache; and although I don't see anything to say that the bug has been closed, I would hope that it has been resolved now

Answer (score 2):

How long the stat cache will cache the information is configurable in your php.ini file using the realpath_cache_ttl variable. Default seems to be 120 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `clearstatcache()` because in [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php) says:

> You should also note that PHP doesn't cache information about
>   non-existent files. So, if you call file_exists() on a file that
>   doesn't exist, it will return FALSE until you create the file. If you
>   create the file, it will return TRUE even if you then delete the file.
>   However unlink() clears the cache automatically.

also to avoid some errors it's better use `is_file()` if You want to check existence of file and `is_dir()` for directory, because `file_exists()` will return true if path that exists both is file or is directory.

p.s. to prove that if file deleted it's not cached: http://joxi.ru/eAO55BF4ojZjmo

about meaning of cache: again read this manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.clearstatcache.php

> When you use stat(), lstat(), or any of the other functions listed in
>   the affected functions list (below), PHP caches the information those
>   functions return in order to provide faster performance.

it means that cache is for file stats, to not to reread it every time, `clearstatcache()` removes stat cache for this file and forces reread them.

P.S. actually it's stupid to cache stats without explicitly enabling it by user with something like: `ini_set('cache_file_stats', true)` it would be better to give control of it to user.

Comment: but if previously file was there and file_exists was called, php will cache file information. and then if file will be removed, file_exists will again return true.

Comment: have You checked in real life?

Comment: In real, checking again after deleting file returns false, but if it is so, what is the meaning of cache ?

Comment: meaning of cache is not to reread stats of file, look at: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.stat.php